# How to convert row into columns in informix

Tags: sql, pivot, informix

| Localcol | Device A | Device B | Device C | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | 11 | 12 | 13 | SA |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | 21 | NA | 23 | PA |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | 31 | 32 | 33 | TA |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | 41 | 42 | 43 | SA |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | 51 | NA | 53 | PA |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | 61 | 62 | 63 | TA |

I need to show this table in below format.

| Localcol | Device | SA | PA | TA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | Device A | 11 | 21 | 31 |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | Device B | 12 | NA | 32 |
| 2021-05-04 21:27:40 | Device C | 13 | 23 | 33 |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | Device A | 41 | 51 | 61 |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | Device B | 42 | NA | 62 |
| 2021-05-04 21:28:00 | Device C | 43 | 53 | 63 |

Please help me to solve this case in Informix 12.10.
Thanks for the support for my previous questions....

Comment: This question is similar to my previous question. so I tried to write the query using that way. but the output is not getting as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Informix 12.10 does not implement CTEs (Common Table Expressions). You'll need to repeat the same query three times to get the result you want.

For example:

```
select
  sa.localcol,
  'Device A' as device,
  sa.device_a,
  pa.device_a,
  ta.device_a
from t sa
join t pa on pa.localcol = sa.localcol and pa.type = 'PA'
join t ta on ta.localcol = sa.localcol and ta.type = 'TA'
where sa.type = 'SA'
union all
select
  sa.localcol,
  'Device B' as device,
  sa.device_b,
  pa.device_b,
  ta.device_b
from t sa
join t pa on pa.localcol = sa.localcol and pa.type = 'PA'
join t ta on ta.localcol = sa.localcol and ta.type = 'TA'
where sa.type = 'SA'
union all
select
  sa.localcol,
  'Device C' as device,
  sa.device_c,
  pa.device_c,
  ta.device_c
from t sa
join t pa on pa.localcol = sa.localcol and pa.type = 'PA'
join t ta on ta.localcol = sa.localcol and ta.type = 'TA'
where sa.type = 'SA'
```